# How to organize or group app registrations in Azure Active DIrectory?

Tags: azure-active-directory

My company uses a single tenant azure active directory. How do i keep app registrations organized such that i classify app registrations per business unit or prod and non-prod etc.?

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into my answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, AAD doesn't provide such a feature that allows you to classify app registrations.

You can manually set their names to the same format to distinguish them. Or add the same type of apps to the same security group.

If you want to restrict different users from using different apps, you need to [Configure an application to require user assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal#configure-an-application-to-require-user-assignment) and [Assign or unassign users, and groups, for an app using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal#assign-or-unassign-users-and-groups-for-an-app-using-the-azure-portal).